# How do I edit a message from a different channel that my bot sent?

Tags: discord.js

I'm making a suggestion module on my bot, and I have everything else down, but am struggling on fetching the message the bot sent and editing it using a command that was sent in a different channel.

I tried doing `await message.guild.channels.cache.get("channel-id-here").messages.fetch("the-actual-messages-id-here").edit({ content: 'Test' })` but it didn't work.

Comment: What about it "didnt work", was there an error?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code, while in theory, should work, most likely doesnt due to unresolved promises.

In the line

```js
await message.guild.channels.cache.get("channel-id-here").messages.fetch("the-actual-messages-id-here").edit({ content: 'Test' })
```

The `await` at the beginning is trying to resolve the promise of the `edit` method, where there is another promise to be resolved at the `<MessagesManager>#fetch` method. In other words you're ignoring the promise returned from the fetch which will resolve no messages. Consider the following change:

```js
const messages = await message.guild.channels.cache.get("channel-id-here").messages;
await messages.fetch("the-actual-messages-id-here").edit({ content: 'Test' });
```

Or if you really want a one-liner (I dont suggest this as it compromises on readability) you could use:

```js
await (await message.guild.channels.cache.get("channel-id-here").messages.fetch("the-actual-messages-id-here")).edit({ content: 'Test'
```